# How to import Visual Assist snippets to Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017, visual-assist, visual-studio-community

I have downloaded the latest Visual Studio Community and InteliSense seems to work well even without the Visual Assist plugin, save a few bugs. I'd therefore like to continue working without the plugin.

I had plenty of code snippets in Visual Assist. How can I migrate them to visual studio 2017 without Visual Assist?

Answer (score 2):

I can get you started:

Visual Studio expects XML:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet

Visual Assist stores its snippets in a legacy, non-XML format. Fortunately, you can "export" XML using the VA Snippet Editor. Open the editor; multi-select in the list; copy; paste into an external editor.

If the snippets you want to export share words in their descriptions or follow a pattern, you can simplify the multi-select by limiting what appears in the list. Change the Type dropdown to "Search", then search a field by string or regex.

I don't have a convenient way to convert from one XML format to the other.

Comment: Jeff you know how I can import my Visual Assist .tpl snippets on my Visual Studio Visual Assist running on another machine? If I simply go to Visual Assist Options -> Performance -> Export & then I copy paste those regedit file AND my .tpl files and paste them on the corresponding directory on the other machine, will I be good to go? Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Copy-and-paste as you describe should work.

You can also copy the directory %APPDATA%\VisualAssist\Autotext from one machine to another.

If you put your VA Snippets on a shared resource, you can modify the registry on your two PCs to use a common set of VA Snippets. Doing so makes modified VA Snippets available without another copy-and-paste. See:

https://support.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W433

Comment: And to reimport those snippets to Visual Assist, just open the VA Snippet Editor again and paste the XML content back! I know the OP does not want to use VA anymore, but since the question title doesn't mention that I stumbled upon this page when searching how to import snippets provided by other people as XML.